# A geometrical shape

Tags: word-request, adjectives, nouns, measure-expressions

I am looking for a specific name of a geometrical shape if there is any.

It is a cylinder.
The height is very short relative to it’s large radius.
It’s very flat, but much thicker than a coin.
Like a cream container or an ointment case, the flat, round ones.

Comment: You'll need to provide an image of the shape.

Answer (score 4):

In geometry, a cylinder doesn't have a height limitation - any 3-dimensional shape with a circle at each end is a cylinder. A coin *is* a cylinder.

Outside of geometry, I would probably use the word "disk" to describe something like a coin.